# JPA Criteria Query. How to get rid of Strings parameters. Build queries without strings in criteria api. Type safe queries

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, types, criteria-api

I am trying to move from JPA JPQL queries for Criteria Query in my app.

The main reason is that I am tired of refactoring strings and fixing a lot of runtime jpa exception cause by **Not typesafe JPQL's**.

I've search web for other JPA solution that will support typesafe and ide refactoring mechanism. Criteria Query seems promising.

One think bothers me in criteria queries:

**Usage of strings in method parameters.**
Can it be somehow replaced with typesafe java objects/ variables, perhaps java reflection?

Below is the example code:

```
public List<BankAccount> findWithBalance(int amount) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<BankAccount> cq = cb.createQuery(BankAccount.class);
    Root<BankAccount> from = cq.from(BankAccount.class);

    ParameterExpression<Integer> balance = cb.parameter(Integer.class);
    cq.select(from);

    Predicate predicate = cb.gt(from.<Integer> get("balance"), balance);

    cq.where(predicate);
    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(from.get("ownerName")));

    TypedQuery<BankAccount> query = em.createQuery(cq);

    query.setParameter(balance, amount);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

As You can see there are to strings:

- "balance"
- "ownerName"

If I will change name of this parameters, I won't get error in IDE or on compile. I will have to test it on runtime, which is not good on large project like mine.

I use:

- JPA with hibernate
- jdbc
- playFramework

Please help.

Comment: Create a metamodel and use that instead of hardcoded values. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html.

Comment: Or use some framework (e.g. http://www.querydsl.com/).

Comment: As alternative to CriteriaQueries I would give a try to QueryDSL (http://www.querydsl.com). QueryDSL-Queries are easier to read and write. The typesafty is also based on generated classes.

Comment: [@M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) thanks for You comment. Can You tell one think about metamodel? Is there possiblity to meta model classe been generated automatically? Or do I have to always manually define that meta model class, creating java class with the same name with underscore at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Metamodel generator seems to be a good solution too:

Example entity:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    Customer customer;
    @OneToMany
    Set<Item> items;
    BigDecimal totalCost;
    // standard setter/getter methods
}
```

Generated metamodel (automatically by eclipse IDE while coding/writing Order class. Each change in original class: `Order`- even without saving file will be automatically updated in `Order_` class):

```
@StaticMetamodel(Order.class)
public class Order_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, Integer> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, Customer> customer;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<Order, Item> items;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, BigDecimal> totalCost;
}
```

Thanks to that we can build type safe sql queries as follow:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> cq = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
SetJoin<Order, Item> itemNode = cq.from(Order.class).join(Order_.items);
cq.where( cb.equal(itemNode.get(Item_.id), 5 ) ).distinct(true);
```

[Original source: JPA metamodels generator](http://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/)

[Hibernate manual](http://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/)

Comment: "Link only" replies are discouraged, because they can be broken whenever the URL becomes broken (server going down, contents moved away, etc.) The question should be answered in your text; after that you can add the links that you think are helpful to provide an in depth explanation.